# A problem occurred evaluating project ':buildSrc'. > Supplied String module notation 'gradleApi()' is invalid

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, gradle, intellij-idea

I am importing Eclipse project(very old) into IntelliJ IDEA and while importing the project getting following error:

```
    A problem occurred evaluating project ':buildSrc'.
> Supplied String module notation 'gradleApi()' is invalid. Example notations: 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2', 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5:javadoc'.
```

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name = 'SpringSource Enterprise Release'
        url = 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release'
    }
    maven {
        name = 'SpringSource Enterprise External'
        url = 'http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile ('gradleApi()')
}

// GAE
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-tools-sdk:1.4.2'
}

dependencies{
    compile "emma:emma:2.0.5312"
}

// Trang
dependencies {
    compile 'com.thaiopensource:trang:20091111',
            'net.sourceforge.saxon:saxon:9.1.0.8'
}

task ide(type: Copy)  {
    from configurations.runtime
    into 'ide'
}
```

I am getting error on the following line:

```
dependencies {
    compile ('gradleApi()')
}
```

Comment: Please check the gradle version and let us know , you can type gradle --version in your command line to get the used version .

Comment: the gradle version is 4.8.1

Answer (score 2):

Don't wrap it in a string, it should be

```
compile gradleApi()
```